# Difference between awaiting straight away or awaiting later on

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I cannot find any information on the actually difference.

So I have always done the following:

```
public async Task<int> DoSomethingAsync()
{
    DoSomethingElse()
    var result = await GetValueAsync();
    var intValue = DoAnotherThing(result);
    return intValue;
}
```

`await` the call and then use it straight after, but I have seen recently a few posts where people are doing the following:

```
public async Task<int> DoSomethingAsync()
{    
    var task = GetValueAsync();
    DoSomethingElse()
    var result = await task;
    var intValue = DoAnotherThing(result);
    return intValue;
}
```

So does this mean that the method `GetValueAsync` is starting it's execution and then we await the result of it later? Or does it mean that it's executing synchronously but it's still `await`able?

Comment: It means your first assumption.

Comment: A lot of people think that `await` *starts* something happening. That's entirely wrong. `await` just waits for something to finish - how that something was started is entirely an implementation detail of other things - in this case, how `GetValueAsync` is internally implemented.

Comment: So far the three answers don't discuss the state machine that is generated, which I think it a potentially important thing to understand too.

Comment: @ColinMackay Good point. I remember it was an interesting hassle to generate IL code that could wrap an async method call because of how the state machine worked.

Comment: It can be very useful when you want to run more than one Task. Start all of them first, then await them.

Comment: You have to love random downvotes, if there is something wrong with the question, please let me know so I can correct it.

Comment: It is very important that you understand Damien's comment. You have a task in hand; a task represents *a computation that might already be completed, or might be completed in the future*. That's **all** you know about it. You do not know that it is running on another thread. You do not know that it is going to be scheduled to perform a computation in the future on this thread. You do not know if it is computationally bound or IO bound. You do not know if it is already complete. You have a task in hand, and it is up to you to decide how to deal with that task.

Comment: "await" means "if the task is not already completed, sign up the remainder of this method as the continuation of that task and return to my caller so this thread can keep doing work".  How the task manages to complete its work is up to the task; you delegated management of that computation to the task.

Comment: Thanks @EricLippert

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Damien_The_Unbeliever is right when he said that it depends on the implementation.

```
class Program
{
    public static int DoAnotherThing(string value)
    {
        return int.Parse(value);
    }

    public static async Task<string> GetValueAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        return "12";
    }

    public static void DoSomethingElse()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }

    public static async Task<int> DoSomethingAsyncA()
    {
        DoSomethingElse();
        var result = await GetValueAsync();
        var intValue = DoAnotherThing(result);
        return intValue;
    }

    public static async Task<int> DoSomethingAsyncB()
    {
        var task = GetValueAsync();
        DoSomethingElse();
        var result = await task;
        var intValue = DoAnotherThing(result);
        return intValue;
    }

    public static void Measure(Action act)
    {
        var sw = new Stopwatch();

        sw.Start();

        act();

        sw.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Measure(() => DoSomethingAsyncA().Wait());
        Measure(() => DoSomethingAsyncB().Wait());

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

In this case `DoSomethingAsyncB` will take ~5 seconds, where `DoSomethingAsyncA` will take ~10. However if your `GetValueAsync` returns a value computation of which was started somewhere else, then there will be no difference.

**UPDATE**
I corrected the mistake in the answer. And here is the output from my machine:

```
  00:00:10:0161446
  00:00:05:0032000
```

Comment: `DoSomethingAsyncB` will take 5 seconds and 10?

Comment: What about `var result = await GetValueAsync(); DoSomethingElse();`? IIUC `DoSomethingElse()` will be called after `GetValueAsync()` has finished, yet I see this style of coding almost everywhere, leaving me wondering what the use of the async-await paradigm is at all.

Answer (score 4):

In this

```
public async Task<int> DoSomethingAsync()
{
    DoSomethingElse()
    var result = await GetValueAsync();
    var intValue = DoAnotherThing(result);
    return intValue;
}
```

It means that when you await the GetValueAsync's result as soon as possible without executing any other code.

The code below means :

```
public async Task<int> DoSomethingAsync()
{    
    var task = GetValueAsync();
    DoSomethingElse()
    var result = await task;
    var intValue = DoAnotherThing(result);
    return intValue;
}
```

You call GetValueAsync and do DoSomethingElse while waiting GetValueAsync to finish it and then when it is finished it continues executing DoAnotherThing

Answer (score 2):

Quite often people think that async-await is done by several threads. Usually this isn't not the case. Unless you start other threads, all code is performed by the same thread. Checking the ThreadId of the current thread will show you this.

In an [interview Eric Lippert explained async-await in a restaurant metaphor](http://www.i-programmer.info/professional-programmer/i-programmer/7154-c-guru-an-interview-with-eric-lippert.html?start=1). Search somewhere in the middle for async await.

He explains that if a cook toasts some bread he can wait until the bread is toasted or start doing something else and come back later to see if the toaster finished toasting.

The same happens in your second DoSomethingAsync. When writing date to a disk, your thread delivers the data to the disk writer. Writing to disks is a relatively slow process. The thread doesn't wait for the date to be written, instead it starts doing something else. When it finished doing something else, the thread awaits until the disk write has finished writing to disk.

This is only useful if the disk write can continue writing while your thread is doing something else. Therefore you usually see async functions when hardware is involved, or processes that start other threads to do some work. If the async function has to do some time consuming calculations it is not useful to make the function async, unless it starts another thread to do the calculations. Even then it is questionable whether this should be done inside an async function or whether the caller should have the freedom to decide whether to let his own thread do the calculations or start a different thread to do this.

[Another article that helped me to understand async-await by Stephen Cleary](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), a great contributor to this site (thanks again Stephen!)

Comment: Good example. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In first example you won't execute code before `GetValueAsync()` return the result.

In the second - you will execute code between `var task = GetValueAsync();` and `var result = await task;` - you will execute `DoSomethingElse()`.

See small example:

```
    public static Task<int> DoLongOperationAsync()
    {
        return Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(5000); return 5; }); // 5 seconds
    }


    public static async Task TestMethod()
    {
        var result = await DoLongOperationAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("Console");
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

    public static async Task TestMethod2()
    {
        var result = DoLongOperationAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("Console");
        Console.WriteLine(await result);
    }


    static async DoSomething()
    {
        await TestMethod(); // here you see some text in console only after 5 seconds

        await TestMethod2(); // here you see some text in console immediately and after 5 seconds you will see "5"

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just defer requirement of a Task result to the statement where it is actually used first time in that way, meaning that by the time execution reaches that statement, task might already have asynchronously set it's result.