# How to get exception or status after async method is done running in the background?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Here's my code I'm trying to simulate. I can remove the async-await to do "fire and forget", but I'm trying to understand the purpose of asynchronous (NON-BLOCKING) code, but it looks like AWAIT is a blocking code before running the method `NextProcess()`. If I remove await, it meets my objective, but is there any way to get any sort of exception or status after it's done running in the background?

```
public static async Task Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Starting the long-running process...");

    await Task.Run(() => LongRunningProcess());

    NextProcess();
}

private static void LongRunningProcess()
{
    // Simulating the work being done
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}

private static void NextProcess()
{
    Console.WriteLine("In See method, continuation without waiting!");
}
```

I tried all sorts of permutations of the code I pasted.

Comment: Ah yes, the infamous sync-over-async pattern. What exactly are you trying to do? As bad as this code is, it's doing what it's supposed to: run `NextProcess` after `LongRunningProcess` is done.

Comment: I wonder if [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38480895/difference-between-awaiting-straight-away-or-awaiting-later-on) about awaiting right away vs awaiting _later_ will help you out.

Comment: `await` doesn't block like a synchronous call does. It waits asynchronously. That means that, for instance, if you use `await` on the UI thread of a WinForms app then that UI thread is still free to handle events that may be raised while it's waiting, which would not be the case with a blocking synchronous call.

Comment: Do you intend to use this knowledge on ASP.NET? If yes, read [this](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html "Fire and Forget on ASP.NET").

Comment: @jmcilhinney when I add await, it seems to blocking the responsiveness of the UI, it's awaiting the completion of the background thread, but my UI cannot be used because of it. If I remove that 'await', it's like 'fire and forget' , the response time is quicker by about 30 seconds which is what I'm aiming for.

Answer (score 5):

> it looks like AWAIT is a blocking code before running the method NextProcess().

You can think of "await" as "asynchronous wait". It does pause the *method* (i.e., it waits), but doesn't block the thread (i.e., it's asynchronous, not synchronous). You may find my [`async` intro](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) helpful.

> If I remove await, it meets my objective, but is there any way to get any sort of exception or status after it's done running in the background?

Sure; the `Task` returned from an `async` method represents the execution of that method. When the method completes, the `Task` is completed, and if the method throws an exception, the `Task` is completed with that exception. In this case, you're using `Task.Run` to execute synchronous code on a thread pool thread, but the same idea applies: the returned `Task` represents the execution of the delegate passed to `Task.Run`.

There's nothing magical about a `Task` instance. You can store the `Task` instance in a variable or whatever and observe it later:

```
public static async Task Main()
{
  Console.WriteLine("Starting the long-running process...");

  var task = Task.Run(() => LongRunningProcess());

  NextProcess();

  await task;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I guess I don't need the AWAIT as it freezes the UI for the amount of time that LongRunningProcess() is taking. What I was aiming for was to execute that NextProcess() without 'awaiting' that LongRunningProcess(), so technically AWAIT blocks the UI.

Comment: @Dave: `await` doesn't block the UI. Feel free to post a follow-up question.